# How to get the top-n files sorted by cognitive complexity in a project using REST API?

Tags: rest, sonarqube, static-code-analysis

How to get the top 500 files in a project sorted by cognitive complexity (using the REST API)? The intent is to export the metric for use with another tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a current SonarQube (8.2, though this would work with earlier versions as well, according to documentation), and presuming your instance is on `localhost:9000` and the project's name is `project1`, this bash script `curl`s SonarQube for top 500 files and their cognitive complexity values, sorted by cognitive complexity, then pretty prints it with `jq`, and displays it in `less`:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                 

curl \                                                                                                                                                                      
"localhost:9000"\                                                                                                                                                           
"/api/measures/component_tree?"\                                                                                                                                            
"component=project1&"\                                                                                                                                                          
"strategy=leaves&"\                                                                                                                                                         
"metricKeys=cognitive_complexity&"\                                                                                                                                         
"s=metric&"\                                                                                                                                                                
"metricSort=cognitive_complexity&"\                                                                                                                                         
"asc=false&"\                                                                                                                                                               
"ps=500" \                                                                                                                                                                  
| jq "[.components[] | {path: .path, cognitive_complexity: .measures[0].value}]" \                                                                                                                                                               
| less
```

Above script produces output as such:

```
[
{
  "path": "desktop/src/main/java/bisq/desktop/main/offer/MutableOfferViewModel.java",
  "cognitive_complexity": "319"
}
{
  "path": "desktop/src/main/java/bisq/desktop/main/offer/offerbook/OfferBookView.java",
  "cognitive_complexity": "304"
}
{
  "path": "p2p/src/main/java/bisq/network/p2p/network/Connection.java",
  "cognitive_complexity": "228"
}
{
  "path": "desktop/src/main/java/bisq/desktop/main/support/dispute/DisputeView.java",
  "cognitive_complexity": "225"
}
{
  "path": "desktop/src/main/java/bisq/desktop/util/GUIUtil.java",
  "cognitive_complexity": "192"
}
...
```